# How to store an array of values of unknown size in a struct

Tags: c, dynamic, malloc, structure, realloc

I currently have this struct that I have created, I have intialised the pointers in main. And I am stuck with the understanding of how to add a value to the pointers then resize it, because it is waiting for user input. The code below is what I in a shortened version, basically I want to know how to add each value of job to the jobNum variable in the struct and resize it so i can store an arbitrary number of values for jobNum. I am quite new to memory allocation.

```
    typedef struct {
         int* jobNum;
     }JobInfo;

   void get_job(JobInfo* jobCalled, int job){
        jobCalled->jobNum = job;

   }
     void main(int argc, char *argv[]){
         jobCalled.jobNum = malloc(sizeof(int));
    
        while(1){
            //Other Processes
            if (USER_INPUT == 'job'){
                 int job = argv[1];
                 get_job(&jobCalled, job);
           }
        }
    
}
```

Comment: "I have intialised the pointers in main." No you did not, please read the compiler warnings and errors you get. Or provide a [mre] of what you are describing.

Comment: `int job = argv[1];` is incompatible assignment, `char*` to `int`. If you assume the argument contains an integral value then you need to parse first – see e.g. [`strtoul`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtoul) or signed counter parts if you expect negative input as well.

Comment: If you want the pointer to hold *multiple* values you need to `malloc` the appropriate number of, i.e. `jobNum = malloc(sizeof(int) * numberOfElements)`, or, if you need the array zero-initialised, `calloc(numberOfElements, sizeof(int))` (otherwise prefer `malloc`). It is recommendable to store the number of allocated elements together with the pointer – or if meaningful the total number of elements available (-> 'capacity') and the number of elements actually contained/used (-> 'size') – proposed wording adopted from C++ STL – if then on appending size exceeds capacity you need to `realloc`.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're having trouble understanding allocation. I would suggest learning about linked lists. Basically in a nutshell:

```
typedef struct{
    void *head;
    void *next;
}myType;
```

```
void addElem(myType *ptr){
    myType *new = (myType*)malloc(sizeof(myType));
    ptr->next = new;
    new->next = NULL;
}
```

This is a barebones way of doing what you're talking about, where the head element points to your first job, but I believe it would suit you to learn about casting, allocation, etc. You will most likely need to create a function that will initialize your head first job as well. You will also likely want to use free to de-allocate memory from the list if you're removing elements. It is also worth noting that it would be better to have a separate type that will be an individual element so that you only allocate one head pointer, but this way is easier if you're having trouble understanding the concept.

Comment: Linked lists is the second step. First, pointers, allocation and even existence of variables and their scopes is needed as foundation knowledge.

Comment: @Yunnosch, I agree, however, I am hoping that being able to see the implementation of concepts(linked lists, etc.) such as malloc will form a better understanding.

Comment: I'd rather start with array based data structure anyway. In general that's more efficient – compare usage of std::vector and std::list in C++...